# JPA One To Many Bi-Directional Stack Overflow Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stack-overflow

Am using Java 1.8, Spring Boot, REST, JPA to create a Spring Boot REST Microservice API which has the following cardinality with its Entity Relationship:

```
Owner can have many Cars.
Cars only have one Owner.
```

Am able to create and view Owners through my REST Web Service.

Everytime I try to create a Car with an associated Owner, it populates the database's row correctly, but seems like it keeps recurses infinitely causes a Stack Overflow error (see below).

---

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>car-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>car-api</name>
    <description>Car REST API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

src/main/resources/applications.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/car-api
server.port=8080
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

# Database specific
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/car_db?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.ownername=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

---

Owner entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    public Owner() {
    }

    // Getter & Setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

Car entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    String make;
    String model;
    String year;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    private Owner owner;

    // Getter & Setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

---

OwnerRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {
}
```

---

CarRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

---

OwnerService:

```
public interface OwnerService {

    boolean createOwner(Owner owner);

    Owner getOwnerByOwnerId(Long ownerId);

    List<Owner> getAllOwners();

}
```

---

OwnerServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class OwnerServiceImpl implements OwnerService {


    @Autowired
    OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    @Autowired
    CarRepository carRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Owner> getAllOwners() {
        return ownerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean createOwner(Owner owner) {
        boolean created = false;
        if (owner != null) {
            ownerRepository.save(owner);
            created = true;
        }
        return created;
    }

    @Override
    public Owner getOwnerByOwnerId(Long ownerId) {
        Optional<Owner> owner = null;
        if (ownerRepository.existsById(ownerId)) {
            owner = ownerRepository.findById(ownerId);
        }
        return owner.get();
    }
}
```

---

CarService:

```
public interface CarService {

    boolean createCar(Long ownerId, Car car);
}
```

---

CarServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

    @Autowired
    OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    @Autowired
    CarRepository carRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean createCar(Long ownerId, Car car) {
        boolean created = false;
        if (ownerRepository.existsById(ownerId)) {
            Optional<Owner> owner = ownerRepository.findById(ownerId);
            if (owner != null) {
                List<Car> cars = owner.get().getCars();
                cars.add(car);
                owner.get().setCars(cars);
                car.setOwner(owner.get());
                carRepository.save(car);
                created = true;
            }
        }
        return created;
    }

}
```

---

OwnerController:

```
@RestController
public class OwnerController {


    private HttpHeaders headers = null;

    @Autowired
    OwnerService ownerService;

    public OwnerController() {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/owners" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "APPLICATION/JSON")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createOwner(@Valid @RequestBody Owner owner) {
        boolean isCreated = ownerService.createOwner(owner);
        if (isCreated) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/owners" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "APPLICATION/JSON")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllOwners() {
        List<Owner> owners = ownerService.getAllOwners();

        if (owners.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(owners, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/owners/{ownerId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "APPLICATION/JSON")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getOwnerByOwnerId(@PathVariable Long ownerId) {
        if (null == ownerId || "".equals(ownerId)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        Owner owner = ownerService.getOwnerByOwnerId(ownerId);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(owner, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

---

CarController:

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

    private HttpHeaders headers = null;

    @Autowired
    CarService carService;

    public VehicleController() {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/cars/{ownerId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "APPLICATION/JSON")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createVehicleBasedOnOwnerId(@Valid @RequestBody Car car, Long ownerId) {
        boolean isCreated = carService.createCar(ownerId, vehicle);
        if (isCreated) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

---

Whereas, I am able to create new owners (and view them in the database & also view them by calling getAllOwners via curl / Postman), by passing this as the request body:

```
{
    "owner": "John Doe"
}
```

---

Inside the database `car_db.owner`:

```
-------------------------------------
|id | name                          |
-------------------------------------  
|1  | John Doe                      |
-------------------------------------
```

---

There is something wrong when I try to create a brand new car for an owner, by using this REST call `/cars/{ownerId}`:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/car-api/cars/1
```

with the following request body:

```
{
    "make": "Honda",
    "model": "Accord"
    "year": 2020
}
```

It inserts it properly inside MySQL database's `car_db.car` table like this:

```
---------------------------------------
|id | make  | model  | year | owner_id|
---------------------------------------  
|1  | Honda | Accord | 2020 |     1   |
---------------------------------------
```

Is there something I am doing inside `CarServiceImpl.createCar() method` its causing bi-directional relationship to break?

Creates a Stack Over Flow : null execption:

```
-03-08 01:43:20,106 ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/car-api] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:512)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:141)
    at com.myapi.model.Car.toString(Car.java:87)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at com.myapi.model.Owner.toString(Owner.java:105)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at com.myapi.model.Car.toString(Car.java:87)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at com.myapi.model.Owner.toString(Owner.java:105)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at com.myapi.model.Car.toString(Car.java:87)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
```

---

The wierd this is that despite this is the Stack Trace that comes every single time I create a new Car, everything is fine in the database (the insert is there inside the car table with the correct ownerId inside the row) and I am able to view the JSON response payload when I do either of these GET requests:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/owners/1
```

Yields:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "cars": [
       {
           "make": "Honda",
           "model": "Accord",
           "year": 2020
       }
    ]
}
```

---

```
GET http://localhost:8080/owners
```

Yields:

```
[
   {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "cars": [
         {
             "make": "Honda",
             "model": "Accord",
             "year": 2020
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

---

Why am I getting this Stack Overflow Error despite all the GETs and the database inserts are working?

Comment: Error is because Owner has cars. Each car again has owner. Then again that owner has cars. So it's going into recursion and giving you stackoverflow error. Inside your Car entity, mark ManyToOne relation with JsonIgnore annotation.

Comment: One more logical issue that I can see in the createCar method is: you are checking if owner is present. Then making new collection of cars and setting new car as this collection. So all previous cars will be cleared. You probably wanted to add new car into the existing cars collection.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) will be helpful.

Comment: @AmitB10 - Thank you very much but the @JsonIgnore annotation inside the Car entity still causes the StackOverflow trace. This works now (I can see the ```cars``` JSON array being populated inside the owner from view the JSON responses via my GET) but the error is still appearing in the logs. What am I possibly doing wrong when setting up my entities?

Comment: Does anyone know why this not working?

Comment: For getters, setters and tostring are you using lombok?

Comment: Have lombok installed in IntelliJ IDEA & Eclipse but if you look at my pom.xml, I am not using lombok for this project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA has nothing to do with this error. Look at the stack trace - your `Car#toString()` prints its `Owner`. While `Owner#toString()` prints its collection of Cars.

So when something in your code calls `toString()` on one of these objects - it causes an infinite chain of invocations which ends only when the max depth of the thread's stack is achieved causing StackOverflowError.

Usually in `toString()` we only want to print primitives/ValueObjects from current class. If we start printing associated Entities as well - this will cause lazy fields to be initialized.

Comment: yes, its because IntelliJ IDEA auto-generated the ```toString()``` method with ```"cars=" + cars```, once I removed this field from the ```toString()``` method, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Inside my Owner class, here's what IntelliJ IDEA generated for my `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
  return "Owner{" +
              "id=" + id +
              "name=" + name + 
              ", cars=" + cars +
        '}';
}
```

When I took out the line containing `", cars=" + cars +`, so it became:

```
public String toString() {
  return "Owner{" +
              "id=" + id +
              "name=" + name +
        '}';
}
```

---

It worked!